# Почему меняется атрибут в конструкторе экземпляра класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь разбираться с ООП в python, и возник такой вопрос:
я создаю 2 экземпляра класса ListAdder. Сразу после создания первого объекта я меняю ему атрибут x.data и затем создаю второй объект этого же класса, но при этом атрибут y.data - уже не пустой список, который инициализируется в конструкторе, а такой же, как и x.data. Почему так происходит? Разве каждый новый объект не должен создаваться с атрибутом self.data, равным пустому списку?

```
class ListAdder:
    def __init__(self, start=[]):
        self.data = start

    def add(self, other):
        self.data.extend(other)
        return self.data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = ListAdder()
    x.add([1, 2])
    print(x.data)
    y = ListAdder()
    print(y.data)

>>> [1, 2]
>>> [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что значения по-умолчанию параметров функции или метода создаются не каждый раз при вызове этой функции/метода, а единожды в момент из создания. Смотрите, когда создается класс `ListAdder`, создаются так же и его методы, и тогда создается объект-пустой список, и указывается, что он является значением по-умолчанию для параметра `start` метода `__init__`, причем этот **один и тот же** объект будет значением по-умолчанию для всех вызовов этой функции.

Когда объект неизменяемый, как, например, число или кортеж, это проблемы не вызывает, но когда он изменяемый, то любые изменения, сделанные в этом объекте, в одном из вызовов функции, отражаются на остальных вызовах.

Вот более простой и наглядный пример, показывающий суть проблемы:

```
>>> def test(l=[]):
...     print('id:', id(l))
...     l.append(1)
...     return l
... 
>>> test()
id: 139654229177416
[1]
>>> test()
id: 139654229177416
[1, 1]
>>> test()
id: 139654229177416
[1, 1, 1]
```

Функция `id` возвращает уникальный идентификатор объекта, и тут мы можем видеть, что при каждом вызове `test`, `l` ссылается на один и тот же список, что и подтверждается возвращаемым значением функции: при каждом вызове список `l` увеличивается на один элемент.

Чтоб избежать этой проблемы, нужно создавать изменяемый объект при каждом вызове самостоятельно. Классическим способом это сделать является установка значения по-умолчанию в `None` с последующей проверкой на то, было ли передано какое-то иное значение, или нет, и в последнем случае, создание нужного объекта (пустого списка в вашем случае).

```
class ListAdder:
    def __init__(self, start=None):
        if start is None:
            # Здесь каждый раз, когда start задан по умолчанию,
            # мы создаем новый экземпляр пустого списка, и
            # присваиваем его переменной start
            start = []
            # Теперь все последующие изменения списка start не
            # затронут остальные вызовы метода.
        self.data = start

    ...
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробное объяснение!